# Keychain iOS 8 kSecAttrAccessible Crash

Tags: ios8, keychainitemwrapper

On iOS8 when I am trying to set the kSecAttrAccessible key before setting my object .I am facing an Assertion failure crash.
KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"KeychainTest" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked forKey:kSecAttrAccessible];
[keychain setObject:@"MySuperSecretPassword" forKey:kSecValueData];
The assertion failure is due to SecItemUpdate() returning a status of -50, which appears to be a generic "invalid parameters" error?

Please can anyone help?
Its similar to [iOS8 + Apple's KeychainItemWrapper results in a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028275/ios8-apples-keychainitemwrapper-results-in-a-crash).
But I don't think we have a clear answer there as well?

Comment: Any updates here? I'm facing the same issue right now.